# Sum by common ID and value in Excel or Python

Tags: python, excel, data-analysis

I have experience with both python and excel and feel comfortable with both so whichever presents a better solution I will use. I have a CSV which I have pasted in this google sheet so you guys can see (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/104nstdSWUWZa22NbCcdeymcITntev346omPhttrL1oc/edit?usp=sharing). What I want to do is take the teams in column B and find the sum of their highest 5 person combination from column M not including any player with position "P" in column D. So essentially I would like something that could find the 5 highest values in column M associated with the same team in column B and sum them together. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Seems like something easily done using Power Query in Excel, or possibly just with formulas.

Comment: I understand how to group and sum in power query but how would I limit to 5 highest values per team that I want to sum?

Comment: In PQ, first filter out the players with `P` in column D.  Then Group by ID.  Then, (and you'll need to write M-Code in the Editor), sort each grouped table and Sum the first 5).

Comment: Sorry I had the link on restricted you should be able to open it now.

Comment: OK, your sheet just became accessible. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some custom m-code for the group aggregation to return the sum of the top 5.

Here is an example using your data:

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Team", type text}, {"Opponent", type text}, {"Position", type text}, {"DFS ID", Int64.Type}, {"SS Projection", type number}, {"My Projection", type any}, {"Actual", type any}, {"Price", Int64.Type}, {"Value", type number}, {"SS Own", type number}, {"My Own", type any}, {"dk_points", type number}, {"dk_25_percentile", type number}, {"dk_50_percentile", type number}, {"dk_75_percentile", type number}, {"dk_85_percentile", type number}, {"dk_95_percentile", type number}, {"dk_99_percentile", type number}, {"fd_points", type number}, {"fd_25_percentile", Int64.Type}, {"fd_50_percentile", type number}, {"fd_75_percentile", type number}, {"fd_85_percentile", type number}, {"fd_95_percentile", type number}, {"fd_99_percentile", type number}, {"fdraft_points", type number}, {"fdraft_25_percentile", type number}, {"fdraft_50_percentile", type number}, {"fdraft_75_percentile", type number}, {"fdraft_85_percentile", type number}, {"fdraft_95_percentile", type number}, {"fdraft_99_percentile", type number}, {"yahoo_points", type number}, {"yahoo_25_percentile", type number}, {"yahoo_50_percentile", type number}, {"yahoo_75_percentile", type number}, {"yahoo_85_percentile", type number}, {"yahoo_95_percentile", type number}, {"yahoo_99_percentile", type number}, {"dk_std", type number}, {"fd_std", type number}, {"fdraft_std", type number}, {"yahoo_std", type number}, {"BatOrder", Int64.Type}, {"PA", type number}, {"Singles", type number}, {"Doubles", type number}, {"Triples", type number}, {"HR", type number}, {"R", type number}, {"RBI", type number}, {"BB", type number}, {"SB", type number}, {"CS", type number}, {"IP", type number}, {"Wins", type number}, {"QS", type number}, {"K", type number}, {"CG", type number}, {"CGSO", type number}, {"Pitches", type number}}),
//remove position P
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Position] <> "P")),

//Group and use a custom aggregation
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Team"}, {
        {"Sum of Top 5", each List.Sum(List.MaxN([dk_points],5)), type number}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

***Note:** The above will return the SUM of the top 5 scores.  So scores of `{8,7,6,5,5,5,5,4,3} => 31`. If you would want to return `45`, that would be a different algorithm.*

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much Ron!!

Comment: If I wanted to do that for Q and R as well would I just copy and paste the "sum of Top 5" function twice below and change the inputs?

Comment: @jf44 Yes, but you would need to give each column a different name. (i.e. Replace `"Sum of Top 5"` with something else.  Columns must have Unique names in a table.